# Test name in the setUp/tearDown methods

Tags: unit-testing, ocunit

SetUp and tearDown methods are called on every test. Is it possible to know the current (running) test name in the setUp and tearDown methods? I need to do some extra work depending on what is the currently running test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selector` method in your `SenTestCase` subclass to get the SEL of the test method that is is going to be executed(in `setUp`) / was executed(`tearDown`). Then you can use `NSStringFromSelector` to convert the SEL to a string.

Here an example:

```
NSString *testToExecute = NSStringFromSelector([self selector]);
```

However I would rethink the way you are writing your test. I don't like the idea of executing conditional code in setUp depending on what test is going to run...
To solve that you better extract that conditional code to a method and call that method from all test methods you want. Or you could even create a separate test class for those test cases, doing that extra work in its setUp/tearDown for all its test methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift: `self.name` or `testRun.test.name` will give you this: `-[AppUITests testLoginFlow]`